# Name error when trying to print an object of a class

Tags: list, class, object, attributes

I'm new to python and need some help. My code is below. I'm trying to get the formatted table from a list of user details  inputted but keep getting error stating 'NameError: name 'games' is not defined' Not sure what I am doing wrong to get it to print, please help.

```
class game():
    def _init_(self,name,platform,genre,no_of_players,online_functionality):
        self.name = name
        self.platform = platform
        self.genre = genre
        self.no_of_players = no_of_players
        self.online_functionality = online_functionality


    def __repr__(self):
        print()
        print("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s" % ("name" , "platform" ," genre" ,"no_of_players","online_functionality"))
        print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%" %(games.name,games.platform,games.genre,games.no_of_players,games.online_functionality))
        print()


    def __str__(self):
        print()
        print("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s" % ("name" , "platform" ," genre" ,"no_of_players","online_functionality"))
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%" %(games.name,games.platform,games.genre,games.no_of_players,games.online_functionality))#formats and aligns columns
        print()

def get_game_from_user():

    gameList =[]
    games = game()
    games.name= input("Enter name of game: ") 
    games.platform= input("Enter Platform (e.g. XBox, PlayStation, PC etc: ")
    games.genre = input("Genre (e.g. Sport, Shooter, Simulation etc.): ")
    games.no_of_players= int(input("Enter number of players: "))
    games.online_functionality= input("Enter if it has online functionality or not : ")
    gameList.append(games)
    print(gameList)
```

Comment: `games.name` and other `games.` inside the methods of the class are incorrect. change them to `self.name` and `self.platform` and so on ...

Comment: Thank you that's printed it. However, it's now stating typeerror __repr__ returned non-string (type nonType) after it prints the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Problem:**

Use `self` inside your class to access to your object not `games`. change these:

```
games.name, games.platform , games.genre, ...
```

and other stuffs like them to these:

```
self.name, self.platform , self.genre, ...
```

**Second problem**:

in your code is that you must **`return`** what you want inside the `__str__` and `__repr__` not `print` them:

```
def __repr__(self):
        result = ""
        result += "%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s" % ("name" , "platform" ," genre" ,"no_of_players","online_functionality\n")
        result += "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
        result += "%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s" %(self.name,self.platform,self.genre,self.no_of_players,self.online_functionality)
        result += "\n"
        return result
```

**source**: [python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, that's working now.